# PDF.js zoom buttons?

Tags: canvas, zooming, pdf.js

I am looking for a way to add zoom-in / zoom-out to my page that shows a PDF (and every page for the PDF) using PDF.JS

Here's the code I have right now:

```
PDFJS.workerSrc = 'js/pdf.worker.js';
var pages = [];
var pdfScale = 1.5;

$(function() {
    $('#pdf-zoom-in').on('click', function() {
        if (pdfScale < 3) {
            pdfScale += 0.5;
        }
    });

    $('#pdf-zoom-out').on('click', function() {
        if (pdfScale > 1) {
            pdfScale -= 0.5;
        }
    });

    function loadPDFJS(pageUrl, canvasContainer) {
        var currentPage = 1;
        var globalPdf = null;
        var container = document.getElementById(canvasContainer);

        function renderPage(page) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var viewport = page.getViewport(pdfScale);

            // append the created canvas to the container
            container.appendChild(canvas);

            // Get context of the canvas
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width  = viewport.width;

            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
            };

            page.render(renderContext).then(function () {
                if (currentPage < globalPdf.numPages) {
                    pages[currentPage] = page;
                    currentPage++;
                    globalPdf.getPage(currentPage).then(renderPage);
                } else {
                    // Callback function here, which will trigger when all pages are loaded
                }
            });
        }

        PDFJS.getDocument(pageUrl).then(function (pdf) {
            if(!globalPdf){
                globalPdf = pdf;
            }

            pdf.getPage(currentPage).then(renderPage);
        });
    }

    loadPDFJS('/path/to/my.pdf', 'pdf-canvas');
});
```

Now I figured if I stored an Array of each PDF page, I should be able to change the scale with .getViewport() but it does not seem to do anything or at least it does not update the view ?

If anyone has a custom viewer or a slimmed down version of the Mozilla viewer with just zoom (and each page shows up if you scroll down instead of clicking next page), then that'd be very helpful :)

Comment: See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/simpleviewer.js -- changing pdfViewer.currentScaleValue or pdfViewer.currentScale shall do what you are looking for.

Comment: @async5 I have looked over the code but I am unsure how to have a layout like the official pdf.js example in which each new page is a new canvas element, as I presume if I zoom in - it'll zoom either only on 1 page or it'll zoom all pages but cut off / look weird between pages as the canvas would still be 800px height or something ?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: I don't remember what I went with in the end. I think I had a toggle zoom level from 'full view' to 'zoomed at 150%' which worked OK but you had to close/zoom-out to switch to the next PDFs.